# What is the proper way to track indexes in python?

Tags: python, indexing, lookup

Right now I am tracking my index in side the loop like this

```
index = 0
for entry in longList:
    if entry == 'foo':
        print index
    index += 1
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185545/python-loop-counter-in-a-for-loop/1185557#1185557

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
for index, entry in enumerate(longList):
    if entry == 'foo':
        print index
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the `enumerate()` built-in function.

```
for index, entry in enumerate(longList):
    if entry == 'foo':
        print index
```

However, in your specific case, you can simply do `index = longList.index("foo")`

**EDIT**: If you want to find the indices of multiple matches pretty much as fast as is possible in pure Python, the following code should do the trick:

```
indices = tuple(index for index, element in enumerate(longList) if element=='foo')
```

Answer (score 6):

I like list comprehension :)

```py
[index for (index,entry) in enumerate(longList) if entry == 'foo']
```

Comment: +1, but the parenthesis around `(index, entry)` are not required. Remember, in Python commas make tuples, not parenthesis. Also, it's usually better to use a generator expression rather than a list comprehension. So, `(index for index, entry in enumerate(longList) if entry == 'foo')`.

Comment: with parenthesis it is easier to read for me :)  Indeed, if you only want to print, take a generator.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the best way is to do this:

```
longList.index('foo')
```

Comment: +1, however, this will raise `ValueError` if `"foo"` isn't a member of `longList` whereas the OP's code will simply not print anything.

Comment: And if we are getting particular, it won't find duplicates.

Comment: I was doing this but when I run it over several thousand entries it keeps getting slower and slower the deeper I get into the list. Which is why I am using the loop I am using now.

Comment: @johnthexiii: You call `.index()` only once. It's definitely faster than any Python code you write yourself since it's a C function.

Comment: Yes but what If I have several entries that match 'foo'? Then isn't going to perform several searches, thus slowing everything down?

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify that you wanted to find multiple instances.

Answer (score 3):

Using enumerate would be a better idea.

```
for ind,item in enumerate(longList):
    if item == 'foo':
        print ind
```

Answer (score 3):

If your list is really long and static, you should consider using a lookup table (actually, a dictionary of index lists with the entry as the key). It will almost pay for itself after the first search, since you currently always iterate over all the elements.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Create and fill the table (only once or whenever the list changes)
lookupTable = defaultdict(list)
for index, entry in enumerate(longList):
    lookupTable[entry].append(index)

# Search the list (as many times as you want)
indexes = lookupTable.get('foo')
# and you get either 'None' or a list of indexes '[1,10,20]'
```

Comment: +1 I could see a lot of application for this, I'll have to do some research on this.