# Write output of for loop to multiple files

Tags: python, file, file-io

I am trying to read each line of a `txt` file and print out each line in a different file. Suppose, I have a file with text like this:

```
How are you? I am good.
Wow, that's great.
This is a text file.
......
```

Now, I want `filename1.txt` to have the following content:

```
How are you? I am good.
```

`filename2.txt` to have:

```
Wow, that's great.
```

and so on.

My code is:

```
#! /usr/bin/Python

for i in range(1,4): // this range should increase with number of lines 
   with open('testdata.txt', 'r') as input:
       with open('filename%i.txt' %i, 'w') as output:
          for line in input:
            output.write(line)
```

What I am getting is, all the files are having all the lines of the file. I want each file to have only 1 line, as explained above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move the 2nd `with` statement inside your for loop and instead of using an outside for loop to count the number of lines, use the `enumerate` function which returns a value AND its index:

```
with open('testdata.txt', 'r') as input:
  for index, line in enumerate(input):
      with open('filename{}.txt'.format(index), 'w') as output:
          output.write(line)
```

Also, the use of `format` is typically preferred to the `%` string formatting syntax.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a great answer, for how to get a counter from a line reader.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185545/python-loop-counter-in-a-for-loop) Generally, you need one loop for creating files and reading each line instead of an outer loop creating files and an inner loop reading lines.

Solution below.

```
#! /usr/bin/Python

with open('testdata.txt', 'r') as input:
    for (counter,line) in enumerate(input):
        with open('filename{0}.txt'.format(counter), 'w') as output:
            output.write(line)
```