# Write output of for loop to multiple files with same filename as input file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of filenames in the file filenames.txt. I am opening all the files one by one, and want to write the result of some operation to a different directory but with the same file name. So far, I tried this, but this won't work. Any help?

```
with open("/home/morty/filenames.txt","r") as f:
    names = [name.strip() for name in f]

for name in names:
    save=open("/home/morty/dir/%name" %name,"w")
    save.write(---some operation---)
```

My question is similar to this, but I don't want the files named by count/enumerate. I want the names to be the same as the input file name:
[Write output of for loop to multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119905/write-output-of-for-loop-to-multiple-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format statement is incorrect. It should be `"/home/morty/dir/%s" %name`

But when you want to join a directory name with a file name, best is to use `os.path.join` like this:

```
for name in names:
    with open(os.path.join("/home/morty/dir",name),"w") as save:
       save.write(---some operation---)
```

(and a `with` context block to make sure that the file is closed when done)