# Write multiple files inside for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

I am trying to crawl several links, extract text found on `<p>` HTML tag and write output to different files. Each link should have its own output file. So far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import pyperclip
import pprint
import requests

urls = ['https://link1',
        'https://link2']
url_list = list(urls)

#scrape elements
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    page = soup.find_all('p')
    page = soup.getText()
for line in urls:
    with open('filename{}.txt'.format(line), 'w', encoding="utf8") as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n'.join([i for i in page.split('\n') if len(i) > 0]))
```

I am getting `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: filenamehttps://link1`

If I change my code into this

```
for index, line in enumerate(urls):
    with open('filename{}.txt'.format(index), 'w', encoding="utf8") as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n'.join([i for i in page.split('\n') if len(i) > 0]))
```

The script runs but I have a semantic error; both output files contain the text extracted from link2. I guess the second for-loop does this.

I've researched S/O for similar [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119905/write-output-of-for-loop-to-multiple-files) answers but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on some sort of `*nix` system as the error has to do with `/` interpreted a part of the path.

So, you have to do something to name your files correctly or create the path you want to save the output.

Having said that, using the `URL` as a file name is not a great idea, because of the above error.

You could either replace the `/` with, say `_` or just name your files differently.

Also, this:

```
urls = ['https://link1',
        'https://link2']
```

Is already a list, so  no need for this:

```
url_list = list(urls)
```

And there's no need for two `for loops`. You can write to a file as you scrape the `URLS` from the list.

Here's the working code with some dummy website:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://lipsum.com/', 'https://de.lipsum.com/']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    page = soup.find("div", {"id": "Panes"}).find("p").getText()
    with open('filename_{}.txt'.format(url.replace("/", "_")), 'w', encoding="utf8") as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n'.join([i for i in page.split('\n') if len(i) > 0]))
```

You could also use your approach with `enumerate()`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://lipsum.com/', 'https://de.lipsum.com/']

for index, url in enumerate(urls, start=1):
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    page = soup.find("div", {"id": "Panes"}).find("p").getText()
    with open('filename_{}.txt'.format(index), 'w', encoding="utf8") as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n'.join([i for i in page.split('\n') if len(i) > 0]))
```

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`.  If I change ``find` to `find_all`, I get `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`. Also, I think there is a learning opportunity for me here; can you explain the line `page=`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using this `page = soup.find("div", {"id": "Panes"}).find("p").getText()` on your `URLs`. I've used this just to illustrate the point. The error you're getting means there's no `div` with the `id` of `Panes` for *your* URLs.