# How can I make my multiple if statements work? Or preferably how do I use nested loops in my code

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

What I want to do, is transform my variable:

```
table = "female\tIngelin\tAleksandersen\nmale\tJohnny\tDigre\nmale\tOsman\tBremseth\nfemale\tCathrine\tDagestad\nfemale\tTirill\tBakker"
```

Into a kind of scheme like this:

1. Row: 0 Col: 0 Cell value: female
2. Row: 0 Col: 1 Cell value: Ingelin
3. Row: 0 Col: 2 Cell value: Aleksandersen
4. Row: 1 Col: 0 Cell value: male
5. Row: 1 Col: 1 Cell value: Johnny

The list is long, so ill stop at 5, but you get the point.
My code so far:

```
table="female\tIngelin\tAleksandersen\nmale\tJohnny\tDigre\nmale\tOsman\tBremseth\nfemale\tCathrine\tDagestad\nfemale\tTirill\tBakker"

def show_table():
    print(table)

def show_every_cell():
    col = -1
    row = -1
    names = table.split("\t")
    for x in names:
        row += 1
        if row == 0:
            col += 1
            if col == 0:
                print('Row: 0 Col: 0 ' + 'Cell value: ' + x)
            if col == 1:
                print('Row: 0 Col: 1 ' + 'Cell value: ' + x)
            if col == 2:
                print('Row: 0 Col: 2 ' + 'Cell value: ' + x)

        if row == 1:
            col += 1
            if col == 0:
                print('Row: 1 Col: 0 ' + 'Cell value: ' + x)
            if col == 1:
                print('Row: 1 Col: 1 ' + 'Cell value: ' + x)
            if col == 2:
                print('Row: 1 Col: 2 ' + 'Cell value: ' + x)

    #The list continues with row: 2, 3 and 4. But no point in showing that part. 

def main():
    show_table()
    show_every_cell()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My output is this:

```
Row: 0 Col: 0 Cell value: female
Row: 1 Col: 1 Cell value: Ingelin
```

As you see, it misses quite a lot....

Comment: You never reset `col` before you print a new row. But this is a prime example for *don't repeat yourself* - instead of writing nearly identical code 4 times, why not use loops?

Comment: Search out any basic tutorial on `for` loops.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185545/python-loop-counter-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comment:

You never reset col before you print a new row. But this is a prime example for don't repeat yourself - instead of writing nearly identical code 4 times, why not use loops?

To reproduce your output, you could use this as a starting point:

```
for rowno, row in enumerate(table.split("\n")):
    for colno, cell in enumerate(row.split("\t")):
        print("Row: {}, Col: {}, Cell value: {}".format(rowno, colno, cell))
```

These are two nested loops, which iterate over the input while using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to automatically count the respective position.

Notice that the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function is used twice: once to split on newlines (`\n`) to get each row, then to split on tabs (`\t`) for each cell.

Since this very much looks like a csv-file, also have a look at the [csv-module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Comment: Thanks, ill give that a shot.

Comment: I added some hints, maybe they help you improving your solution further.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should try a nested `for` loop.
...

```
for x in names:
   for row in range(number_of_rows):
      for col in range(number_of_cols):
         print('Row: ' + row + 'Col: ' + col + 'Cell value: ' + x)
```